# Cambio de HTTP a HTTS Apache, muchas URL,S no se redirigen

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

Hace unos días compré un SSL para mi web con el proveedor de hosting que tengo, utiliza Apache, ellos mismos me lo instalaron en mi dominio, con el protocolo https:// la página salvo algún error de recursos que tengo que poner sus rutas adecuadamente funciona perfectamente, pero cuando ingresas a través de Http la cosa cambia, si tratas de ingresar a la página con `http://www.dominio.com` te redirige bien al https pero si ya tiene algún parámetro extra la URL como `http://www.dominio.com/seccion` te redirige a
`htts://www.dominio.comseccion/`(una página inexistente), la versión http de la web se ha perdido por completo y necesito que este visible y que redirija lógicamente al protocolo https://, he intentado con .htaccess y casi todo lo que he encontrado en internet es algo así:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.dominio.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Tanto si añado esto al .htaccess como si no lo añado igualmente se puede hacer la redirección de http a https sin problemas pero solo a la URL del dominio, no al de resto de secciones que solo aparecen en protocolo https y necesito que también este funcional y redirigiendo correctamente con protocolo http. No se si alguien del foro me pueda echar una mano, si es de .htaccess no tengo idea y con los generadores de este tipo de ficheros que hay on-line no termina de funcionar correctamente. Por lo que leo en otro tipo de preguntas relacionadas en este foro el SSL es de un solo dominio, no tiene wildcard y el página esta hecha con CMS que desarrolle hace ya algún tiempo, este tipo de SSL en wordpress no me ha dado guerra.

De antemano muchas gracias y saludos a tod@s!

Answer (score 2):

Pon estas lineas en tu .htacces

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Es la más habitual para redirigir a https si la petición no usa ese protocolo

Comment: Gracias Juan por tu pronta respuesta! Ese es unos de los código que había ya probado previamente y no sale... si encuentro la respuesta la compartiré... Saludos y mil gracias!

Comment: ¿Y no te funciona? Supongo que cuando accedes directamente si funciona el acceso seguro. ¿Has comprobado si otros rewrites funcionan? Lo digo por asegurarte que tienes el modulo rewrite cargado la configuración del servidor.

Comment: Hola @JuanPerez! Sigo con el mismo problema y en efecto otras reescrituras si funcionan, lo que veo es que todo lo que vaya por URL con variables se reescribe sin problema creando anidamientos `http://www.dominio/variable/variable` ... pero lo que realmente sin son carpetas  `http://www.dominio/carpeta`  (carpeta que es una sección donde tiene su propio index.php) este tipo de URLS se redirigen mal hacia el `https://www.dominio.comcarpeta/ `, lógicamente da error de URL desconocida.. Seguiré prueba y error, seguro luego será algo más obvio de lo que creo... Saludos!! Y gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: O sea, se come la /, has probado a añadir la barra al final de REQUES_URI? De todas formas añada antes los flags QSA (después de R=301) esto mantiene lo que vaya depues de la url (parámetros get por ejemplo).

Comment: Hay otras formas , se puede comprobar el puerto 80 para saber si es una llamda no https,     
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]     
A ver si este si te sirve.

Comment: Una disculpa, finalmente no logré solucionarlo por eso ya no te escribí Juan, gracias por tu tiempo y tus respuestas, finalmente la web se esta posicionando bien con las nuevas URL`S, entiendo era el mayor detrimento. De todas maneras si encuentro una solución la posteare, Saludos y mil gracias!